# How to prove set equality based on the fact that the sets have identical truth tables?

Tags: logic

> Let $x \in A$ be logic statement $p$ and $x \in B$ be statement $q$. Prove that $(A \oplus B)'= A' \oplus B$ **using the fact** that LHS and RHS have identical truth tables.

For LHS:
$$
(A \oplus B)' = (A' \cup B) \cap (B' \cup A)\iff \{x:(x\notin A \lor x \in B) \land (x \notin B \lor x \in A) \} \\\iff (\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor p)
$$
While for RHS:
$$
A' \oplus B = (A' \cap B') \cup (B \cap A) \iff \{x: (x \notin A \land x \notin B) \lor (x \in B \land x\in A)\} \\\iff (\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor (p \land q)
$$
Using Wolfram Alpha the logical statements have the same truth tables ([LHS](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((NOT%20p)%20OR%20q)%20AND((NOT%20q)%20OR%20p)) and [RHS](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((NOT%20p)%20AND%20(NOT%20q))%20OR%20(p%20AND%20q))).

But as far as I know two sets are equal iff they have the same elements. How can I use the fact of identical truth tables to help me?

Comment: Your have a logical (or at least notational) flaw here: "one set equals some other set is logically equivalent to some set, is logically equivalent to a statement" make s no sense.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I wanted to say that $(A \oplus B)'$ means that/is equivalent to the logical statement. I'm not sure what notation should be used for this.

Comment: The notation is that the set construction is the set, so for instance  :  $$A\cap B {~= \{x: x\in A\wedge x\in B\} \\~= \{x: p\wedge q\}}$$  That is: the union of sets A and B is the set of entities for which the statement $p\wedge q$ is satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principle is that $\{x: P(x)\} = \{x: Q(x)\}$ if and only if $\forall x:( P(x)\leftrightarrow Q(x))$.   That is: the sets will be equal exactly when the predicates that construct them are identical.

The predicates describe *which* elements are(or are not) in the set, after all.

You should have $$\begin{align}(A\oplus B)' &= \{x: \neg((x\in A \wedge x\notin B)\vee(x\notin A\wedge x\in B))\} &&\text{by definition of }\oplus \\ &= \{x: \neg ((p\wedge \neg q)\vee(\neg p\wedge q))\} \\ &= \{x: (\neg p\vee q)\wedge(p\vee\neg q))\} \\ &~~\vdots &&\text{see table.}\\ & = \{x: (\neg p\wedge \neg q)\vee(p\wedge q)\}\\ &= \{x: (x\in A'\wedge x\notin B)\vee(x\notin A'\wedge x\in B)\} \\ &= (A'\oplus B) &&\text{by definition of }\oplus
\end{align}$$

$\bbox[lemonchiffon,border:1pt solid blue]{\begin{array}{c:c|c:c:c:c|c:c} p & q & p\wedge q & p\wedge \neg q & \neg p\wedge q & \neg p\wedge \neg q & \neg( (p\wedge\neg q)\vee (\neg p\wedge q)) & (\neg p\wedge \neg q)\vee (p\wedge q)\\ \hline \top & \top & \top & \bot & \bot & \bot & \top & \top\\ \hdashline \top & \bot \\ \hdashline \bot & \top \\ \hdashline \bot &\bot
\end{array}}$

Comment: If I complete the "why" step in your explanation then I wouldn't need truth tables. As far as I understand I should arrive to the step when $(A \oplus B)'=...= \{x : (\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor p)\}$ and then separately $(A' \oplus B) = ... = (\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor (p \land q)$ and then I can say that because the truth tables are equal therefore the two sets are equal because as you mentioned $\{x: P(x)\} = \{x: Q(x)\}$ iff $\forall x:( P(x)\leftrightarrow Q(x))$

Comment: You don't need truth tables, @Yos . Use distribution.

Comment: That's definitely one way to solve it but in the OP I'm explicitly asking for a way to solve it using truth tables.

Comment: @Yos Then just fill in a truth table and verify the relevant columns have the same value in every row.

Answer (score 1):

Show that
$$x\in(A\oplus B)'\iff x\in A'\oplus B$$
by using the definitions of $\oplus$ and ${}'$ to convert both sides into logical combinations of $p$ and $q$.